# Java:How to use two different logging systems depending on running environment

Tags: android, log4j, logging

I have developed an application/library that use apache log4j library. 
Now i want to use the library also into an Android application, where the usual log4j library doesn't work.

Now i know that there are some libraries lis slf4j o log4j for android, but my idea is to use where available log4j library (then when the library is running onto a computer) and use the Android logging facilities when it is running on Android devices.

Is possible to do that? 
I think that the solution should be to implement an internal Logger class that select the available logging system.

- Is it a good idea?
- Or is better to choose only one logging system?
- Or maybe is better that the internal logger class is implemented in two separate versions the first for real pc and the second for Android.

And also:

- how can i detect the running environment? (Is it on Android or is it on a computer?  is it sufficient to detect if i'm on a DalvikVM or a JavaVM? Is it possible?

Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: A common approach is to use reflection to find out if a certain package/class is available at runtime and depending on that to create your platform-specific interface objects via the factory pattern.

Comment: good idea, i didn'think about that! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java Logging. It's available on [android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) too. This api on android seem that delegates on android.util.Log.

Note that by default only messages INFO and up are printed on logcat. In case you want to see lower log leves you can setprop on the device ([more info](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#stdout)):

```
adb -e shell setprop log.name DEBUG
```

And remember to set the java log level on your library:

```
Logger.setLevel (java.util.logging.Level.FINER);
```

Hope this help